# Why is this django url regex eating all of the urls below it?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I cannot get Django to hit any urls that share a common root with other urls. This has to be a regex problem on my end, but I'm [staring at the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/), and as far as I can tell, things are formatted correctly.

My `urls.py` looks like this:

```
...
url(r'(?P<pagename>\w)/$', views.show_page, name='page'),
url(r'(?P<pagename>\w)/info/$', views.show_info, name='info'),
```

The problem is that the first regex in the list eats all of the regexs that follow it. So, for instance, if I navigate to:

```
mysite.com/page/some-page-name/
```

the first pattern matched is `r'(?P<pagename>\w)/$'`. However, if I attempt to navigate to:

```
mysite.com/page/some-page-name/info/
```

It still chooses the first regex, and the fires the `show_page` view, instead of the `show_info` one.

If I comment out the first regex.

```
...
# url(r'(?P<pagename>\w)/$', views.show_page, name='page'),
url(r'(?P<pagename>\w)/info/$', views.show_info, name='info'),
```

Then I can hit the `page-name/info/` url no problem. Similarly, if I rearrange the url order I can hit the correct page. However, from Django's examples, I should be able to stack them according to specificity. e.g.

```
url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', views.year_archive),
url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/$', views.month_archive),
url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d+)/$', views.article_detail),
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Per suggestions:

I added the `^` character to the urls patter, but now neither one works!

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<pagename>\w)/$', views.show_page, name='page'),
    url(r'^(?P<pagename>\w)/storecomment/$', views.show_info, name='info'),
)
```

For completeness, here is the project's `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'main.views.index'),
    url(r'^page/', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And the error I get when hitting:

```
mysite.com/page/some-page-name/
mysite.com/page/some-page-name/info/


Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^__debug__/
^$
^page/^(?P<pagename>\w)/$ [name='page']
^article/^(?P<pagename>\w)/info/$ [name='info']
^admin/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to additionally check for the beginning of the string (`^`):

```
url(r'^(?P<pagename>\w)/$', views.show_page, name='page'),
url(r'^(?P<pagename>\w)/info/$', views.show_info, name='info'),
```

Without it `(?P<pagename>\w)/$` regex would catch both `some-page-name/` and `some-page-name/info/` urls, since it is checking for a single alphanumeric character, a slash and an end of the string:

```
>>> re.search(r'(?P<pagename>\w)/$', 'p/').group(1)
'p'
>>> re.search(r'(?P<pagename>\w)/$', 'p/info/').group(1)
'o'
```

Comment: Hmm.. I might be an idiot. I added the `^` characters, but now neither works! D: I updated the question with more info (including my project level urls.py

Comment: @user3308774 well, I'm still not sure why are you trying to catch only single `\w` character. What if you try `^(?P<pagename>\w+)/$` and `^(?P<pagename>\w+)/info/$` respectively. Let me know, thanks.

Comment: ah, because I had a pretty large misconception about what `\w` meant. It wasn't connecting that it was matching a single letter. I added the `+` and your example now works perfectly. Thanks a ton!